# React Trypescript Axios response data mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a problem with using the response that I get with axios from a simple weather API - specifically, I'm having trouble mapping the response.

The `.map()` function does not work since my response is an object, I get that. My WeatherApi component returns the response - an object.

I then want to import the WeatherApi component into my App component and then access the data inside it like: `weather.location.name` and either map everything in advance to variables (like in the interface) or just do it on the fly when rendering the HTML like `<h1>{weather.location.name}</h1>`.

If I do this, I either get errors in the app that sometimes weather is undefined or build / type errors that `.location` does not exist on type `WeatherData[]` which it does (check below).

How can I map everything nice and tidy to use in my App component?

**WeatherApi.ts**

```
const WeatherApi = () => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState<WeatherData[] | null>([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const url:string = 'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=d7db22f333fc4e6aaf3110311222601&q=London&aqi=no';

    axios
      .get<WeatherData[]>(url)
      .then(res => {
       setWeather(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  },[])

  return weather ? weather : null
}

export default WeatherApi
```

**WeatherData.ts**

```
export interface WeatherData {
    location: Location
    current: Current
  }
  
  export interface Location {
    name: string
    country: string
    localtime_epoch: number
    localtime: string
  }
  
  export interface Current {
    temp_c: number
    is_day: number
    condition: Condition
    feelslike_c: number
  }
  
  export interface Condition {
    text: string
    icon: string
    code: number
  }
```

**App.tsx**

```
import WeatherApi from '../api/WeatherApi'

const Weather = () => {
    const weatherData = WeatherApi()

    // map weatherData here like in interface
    // const name = weatherData.location.name
    // const temp = weatherData.current.temp_c
    // etc.

  return (
    <div>
      // or add the data directly here as {weatherData.location.name} etc.
    </div>
  )
}

export default Weather
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since you use a hook into `WeatherApi()` (the `useEffect`) you actually need to name it something like `useWeatherApi()` in order for react to understand it is actually a hook.

And use it like so

```
const Weather = () => {
    const weatherData = useWeatherApi()

    // map weatherData here like in interface
    // const name = weatherData.location.name
    // const temp = weatherData.current.temp_c
    // etc.

  return (
    <div>
      // or add the data directly here as {weatherData.location.name} etc.
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. Maybe I'm missing something? I changed the import and variable assignment to `useWeatherApi()` but everything remains the same

Comment: I just checked your code real quick in a sandbox and it appears the typing of the hook is not correct (an array of weather data) when contacting the api, it responds with a single WeatherData object. You can check this updated version of the typings in the hook https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-microservice-3vm02r?file=/src/hooks.ts

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the late reply, the site was down for a bit - this worked, thank you so much. I didn't realize that the array type was messing up the whole response. I can access the data freely now in the main component - thank you once again!

Comment: You're welcome :) Have fun with the code!